# Windows Explorer crashes in Windows 7 when USB mouse is un-plugged

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, crash

windows Explorer crashes in Windows 7 whenever USB mouse is un-plugged. Previously, it was working well. I guess the reason could be some latest windows update. I'm having this issue for a couple of weeks. How to resolve this issue.